# Email to case functionality based on incoming customer's template email?

Tags: case, email2case

I'm very new to Salesforce. Our requirement is to create cases directly from email (Email to case). Each of our customer has their own service request template/form. These email templates/forms will be be filled out internally by the customer explaining their service issues and then send an email to our organization for the case to be created. We have around 25 different case request templates. Once an email is sent, we are supposed to scan/examine the incoming customer email body/ email template and take out the key information and create cases. How do I automate this process? All cases will be created in the same case record type. What are my options? I would really appreciate if someone can guide me with this tricky requirement. We don't want the email body to be dumped in to the case description. I've researched online but was unable to find any solution or suggestion for my requirement.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a two step process here? *These email templates/forms needs to be filled out by the customer explaining their service issues and then send an email to our organization for the case to be created.* -- Why would you ask a customer to fill a form and then send an email? How is the form details then captured in the Email by the customer?

Comment: Hey Jayant, May be I didn't explain it clearly. Sorry for that. Each of our customer has their own service request template/form. When the require a service issue assistance, they fill out their form/template internally with the details and send it to our organization's managed services email address. Previously, the CSR agents go through these emails, pull out the key information and create cases. We want this process to be automated through email to case.

Comment: So I will imagine you get those templates as attachments on the Email. Do you plan to "parse" the contents from the attachments as well or already have one in place?

Comment: No. We would get them as an email body. Please refer to attached image in my question. That's how typically our incoming emails will be.

Comment: If you have control over the sender, it might be worth creating an attachment of json with the same information from the form, so you can easily parse it into data from the mail. Maybe even replace the email templates with a public site where users can submit issues through a form instead of email?

Comment: Hello, We do know the actual format of the templates/forms that our customers sends us. Any way we can parse the  Problem description, Assignment, Order status and Warranty data from the email (please look at the attached image) and assign it them to their respective case fields? I would really appreciate if you can provide me with any leads. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once an email is sent, we are supposed to scan/examine the incoming customer email body/ email template and take out the key information and create cases.

Based on what you need here is going to be very complicated. You can definitely automate the process of Email-to-Case, but looking through the body of the email and creating respective record types will require you to parse the body of the email and accordingly identify the values that you expect. And this cannot be fool-proof because there can be typo, the value may not be available, etc. etc. and that you end up with a complex parsing logic here.

One of the ways here can be to "ensure" that the "Subject" of the incoming email is classified with some information which you can utilize to create certain record types. E.g., say you have a subject as "*Template 1: Request to create case*", you can easily get this information from the Subject field of the inbound email message, thus creating the case of a specific type.

But again, this assumes that the incoming email message follows a pattern. But at least this is better than scanning the whole body of the email and performing operations. I do not know of any option where you can parse the email body without much of complexities.

In general, I will not recommend to go through a route which is not certain and that you end up having issues.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs Jayant. That was helpful.  All our service related cases will be created in the same case record type. So, Isn't there any uncomplicated way, where we can take out the information and assign them to particular fields instead of dumping the email body in the case description?

Comment: Putting anything to a particular field from email will ultimately end up you parsing the email body.

Comment: Let's just assume that we only have only to deal with one type of email body. What would be an ideal way to parse the email body which will update the fields and create a case?

Comment: You just get the body of the email and keep finding the values that you want. It has to be a custom implementation and that's not going to be an effective approach at all.

Comment: Can we do it through Apex InboundEmailHandler?

Comment: Yes, and I will recommend going through documentation for that.